# Setting a control's location and dimension in Swing

Tags: java, swing

Coming from Windows Forms (.net), I'm tempted to write the following code:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JList list = new JList();
    list.setLocation(new Point(50, 50));
    list.setSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    list.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(list);

    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setLocation(new Point(0, 0));
    button.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
    button.setText("myButton");
    button.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(button);
```

That should create a window (frame) with a 300x200 size and a list and a button at (50,50) and (0, 0).

Yet when I run the code, all I see is a button (covering the whole area). I guess this must have some special layout system, but I'd like to know how to just put the controls in the specified (x,y) locations with the specified (w,h) dimensions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Swing, if you don't specify any layout manager to a [top-level container](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html), [`BorderLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) is used. This layout manager gives you the result you have.

If you want to use absolute positioning, you have to disable the default layout manager first:

```
frame.setLayout(null);
```

Then, you can place your components.

Comment: "The default content pane will have a `BorderLayout` manager set on it."—[JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html). `JPanel` defaults to `FlowLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use Layout Managers:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Although you might be tempted to manually specify a location and size, I would recommend against this unless absolutely necessary.  It might seem like learning to use a layout manager is a waste, but the investment will be worth it in the long run.

Comment: You're right on using LayoutManagers whenever possible (+1). Just in case you'd really (like in REALLY) need to do it manually, use the "null" LayoutManager (`setLayout(null)`).

Answer (score 1):

What you would be looking for here is a null layout manager.
If you are looking to specify the exact size and location of the objects, then you can use your approach from above.

Take a look at this article
http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1205/java-null-layout-manager-swing/

The author, has the same type of example as you, the major difference is the addition of the line

```
getContentPane().setLayout(null);
```

In your current implementation you have the default layout, so you would just be layering the list and button on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

You need absolute positioning. Just set the container's layout manager to null by calling `setLayout(null)`.

Here is the link:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html